# Spark-Cassandra connector: how to change collections write behavior

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

In Java, I have a Spark dataset (Spark Structured Streaming) with a column of type `java.util.ArrayList<Short>` and I want to write the dataset in a Cassandra table which has a corresponding `list<smallint>`.

Each time I write the row in Cassandra it updates an existing row and I want to customize the write behavior of the `list` in order to control if

- the written list will **overwrite** the existing list or
- the content of the written list will be **appended** to the content of the list already saved in Cassandra

I found in the `spark-cassandra-connector` source code a class [`CollectionBehavior`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/ColumnRef.scala) which is extended by both `CollectionAppend` and `CollectionOverwrite`. It seems exatcly what I am looking for but I didn't find a way to use it while writing to Cassandra.

The dataset is written to Cassandra using:

```
dataset.write()
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .option("table", table)
    .option("keyspace", keyspace)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save();
```

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: Cassandra is meant for high write throughput.  to achieve this it use immutable SST . so logical the Cassandra is not this type of use case   .

Answer (score 0):

To save to Cassandra collections while setting the save mode for the collection, use the RDD API. Dataset API seem to be missing this so far. So changing the dataset to RDD and using RDD methods to save to cassandra should be able to give you the behaviour you want.

> https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md